# Determing MSS value on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, tcpip

In [this Technet article about the MSS limitations of Windows Server 2008](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nettracer/archive/2010/07/30/why-doesn-t-windows-2008-server-send-tcp-segments-smaller-than-536-bytes.aspx), it mentions:

> After analyzing the network trace collected on the source Windows 2008
>   Server, we found out that the remote system was offering a TCP MSS
>   size of 512 bytes and Windows 2008 server kept sending the data
>   packets with an MSS size of 536 bytes

How do you go about doing this, i.e. doing a network trace and then determine the MSS value Windows should be using and is currently using?

Comment: `How do you go about doing this` means? You want to know why they do that or how they do that?

Answer (score 3):

If you do have a packet capture with the SYN and SYN/ACK packets initiating the TCP connection, you will find the maximum segment size announced by each of the parties in the options list. You can create such a capture using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), the interesting part can look like this:

[image: wireshark packet capture]
(shamelessly stolen from http://caedesnotes.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/bug-hunting-browsers-fail-to-load-research-microsoft-com/)

If - as you see in this example - the MSS announced by 131.107.65.14 is 1452 bytes, you only should see TCP segment lengths equal to or smaller than this value during this connection. Note that both hosts announce the MSS independently in the SYN and the SYN/ACK packets and the smaller of the two is chosen for all segments exchanged during the entire duration of the connection.

You can set up a display filter in Wireshark to do a quick verification. `tcp.len>1452 and ip.dst==131.107.65.14` would display any packets violating the MSS restriction of 1452 bytes to 131.107.65.14. If your TCP stack is doing it right, you obviously should not see any packets displayed after the filter has been applied.

Comment: Wireshark is your friend